# CQLSH escaping multi-line comment (slash asterisk)

Tags: cassandra, escaping, comments, cqlsh

I am using cqlsh command line utility to load some DDLs.

The version of utility I use is this:

```
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.0.47 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
```

Command that loads DDL.cql:

```
cqlsh -u username -p password cassandra.example.com 65503 --ssl -f DDL.cql
```

I have a line in cql script that breaks the syntax.

```
INSERT into tablename (key,columnname1,columnname2) VALUES 
   ('keyName','value1','/value2/*/value3');
```

`/*` is interpreted as start of multi-line comment. It used to work on older versions of cqlsh.

Is there a way to escape this sequence?

The error we see looks like this:

```
SyntaxException: line 4:2 mismatched input 'Update' expecting ')' (...,'value1','/value2INSERT into tablename(INSERT into tablename (key,columnname1,columnname2)) VALUES ('[Update]-...)
SyntaxException: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input '(' ([(]...)
```

Same behavior while running is interactive mode too.

Comment: looks like a bug, maybe makes sense to open Jira

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt!, I filed a [jira report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17667)

Comment: @nixtalker out of curiosity, what version is 4.0.0.47? Is it a forked version of Apache Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it used to work in Cassandra 3.11 (I tested C* 3.11.13 in particular). For some reason, it doesn't work for any versions of C* 4.0 beginning from 4.0.0.

Thanks for logging [CASSANDRA-17667](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17667) which we're triaging now. I haven't figured out which change broke it but hopefully we'll get it fixed sometime soon. Cheers!